# How do you express "All Suffering" or "Everything Is Pain" with the omni- prefix?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'd like to know the equivalent of omniscient but for pain instead of knowledge.

Are omnidolens or omnipassionis correct (they couldn't be)?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The present active participles are *patiens* and *dolens*, so the anglicized words with the *omni-* prefix would be *omnipatient* and *omnidolent*. The former, according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/omni-patient), has the definition:

> Having unlimited endurance; infinitely patient.

*Omnidolent*, on the other hand, doesn't appear in any dictionary that I know of. However, the term was used by [Samuel Beckett](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=iUwStqNL3CUC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=omnidolent&source=bl&ots=y2lEpfCdQG&sig=ACfU3U3a-f6QAGkJlv0ak_TEz_wpd43wpg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkpfTnsKTpAhUCHbkGHVq5BzsQ6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=omnidolent&f=false), who wrote:

> To be nothing but pain, how that would simplify matters! Omnidolent!
>   Impious dream.

From the context, it's seems he understood it to mean *feeling all pain*.

Comment: This answers my question, I've marked it as such. Thank you for your time and details.

Comment: You're welcome.